# How can I select the property for OrderBy/Where at runtime (not with a string parameter)?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

Updated example to show more general usage.

I have an entity to allow user-provided localization:

```
public class ResourceValue
{
    public int ResourceValueId { get; set; }
    public string EnglishValue { get; set; }
    public string FrenchValue { get; set; }
    public string SpanishValue { get; set; }
    etc...
}
```

Used on many other entities like this:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ResourceValue Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ResourceValue ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual ResourceValue LongDescription { get; set; }
    etc...
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
return context.SomeEntities.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

And have that work as if I had done this:

```
return context.SomeEntities.OrderBy(x => x.Name.FrenchValue);
```

based on the CurrentUICulture being "fr-CA".

I have been trying some things based on Marc Gravell's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1231941 but haven't been able to get quite what I want.

Update - This is pretty close, but I would rather have it be named just "OrderBy" so the end-coder can use it without special consideration:

```
    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
    {
        return ApplyLocalizedOrder(source, keySelector, "OrderBy");
    }

    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> ApplyLocalizedOrder<TSource, TKey>(IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, string methodName)
    {
        ParameterExpression arg = keySelector.Parameters[0];
        Expression expr = Expression.PropertyOrField(keySelector.Body, GetCurrentCulture());
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, string>>(expr, arg);

        return (IOrderedQueryable<TSource>)typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Single(
                method => method.Name == methodName
                        && method.IsGenericMethodDefinition
                        && method.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2
                        && method.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource), expr.Type)
                .Invoke(null, new object[] { source, lambda });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While creating lambda expressions dynamically is cool you can achieve your result in a much simpler way just by creating a method that will apply the sort on top of your query. The method would just look like this:

```
    private static IQueryable<SomeEntity> OrderByName(IQueryable<SomeEntity> source, string culture)
    {
        if (culture == "fr-CA")
        {
            return source.OrderBy(x => x.Name.FrenchValue);
        }

        return source.OrderBy(x => x.Name.EnglishValue);
    }
```

And then you would just use it as follows:

```
OrderByName(context.SomeEntities, "en-US")
```

Here is the entire example:

```
public class MyCtx1 : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SomeEntity> SomeEntities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ResourceValue> ResourceValues { get; set; }
}

public class SomeEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ResourceValue Name { get; set; }
}

public class ResourceValue
{
    public int ResourceValueId { get; set; }
    public string EnglishValue { get; set; }
    public string FrenchValue { get; set; }
}

class Program
{

    private static IQueryable<SomeEntity> OrderByName(IQueryable<SomeEntity> source, string culture)
    {
        if (culture == "fr-CA")
        {
            return source.OrderBy(x => x.Name.FrenchValue);
        }

        return source.OrderBy(x => x.Name.EnglishValue);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new MyCtx1())
        {
            if (!context.SomeEntities.Any())
            {
                context.SomeEntities.Add(
                    new SomeEntity() 
                    { 
                        Name = new ResourceValue()
                        {
                            EnglishValue = "abc - en",
                            FrenchValue = "xyz - fr"
                        }
                    });

                context.SomeEntities.Add(
                    new SomeEntity() 
                    { 
                        Name = new ResourceValue()
                        {
                            EnglishValue = "xyz - en",
                            FrenchValue = "abc - fr"
                        }
                    });

                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Ordered by english name");
            DisplayResults(OrderByName(context.SomeEntities, "en-US"));

            Console.WriteLine("Ordered by french name");
            DisplayResults(OrderByName(context.SomeEntities, "fr-CA"));
        }
    }

    private static void DisplayResults(IQueryable<SomeEntity> q)
    {
        foreach (var e in q)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Id);
        }                
    }
```

And the result:

```
Ordered by english name
1
2
Ordered by french name
2
1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: That would work in this specific case, but I would like to use the ResourceValue on dozens of fields across many entities.  SomeEntity might also have a localizable ShortDescription, LongDescription, etc. for instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
context.SomeEntities.Select(v => v.Name.FrenchName).OrderBy(x => x);
```

But even better than that in your `get` for name, return the current culture or a certain culture or whatever your code is calling for, no reason to do it in the Linq query when your class could do it. when it done in the class it is better anyway because then anywhere you call the code it is returning the correct culture.